# C++ CFile sharing with C# App not working?

Tags: c#, c++, cfile

I'm having trouble getting a file created and populated with a c++ application to be read by a different c# application while it's still open in the c++ application.

I create the file with the line:

```
txtFile.Open(m_FileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyWrite, &e)
```

I've also tried using the lines:

```
txtFile.Open(m_FileName, CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite|CFile::shareDenyNone, &e)
```

and:

```
txtFile.Open(m_FileName, CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite, &e)
```

with the same results.

Then in the c# app I've tried 2 different ways of opening the file:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilepath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();
```

and

```
byte[] buffer;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(inputfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Both methods catch the error:

The process cannot access the file 'filename.txt' because it is being used by another process.

The c++ app creates the file, then uses CreateProcess to run the c# app.

I expect the issue to be in the c# code where I try read the file as notepad gives no errors when I add share permissions in the c++ app, but does give errors when I don't set permissions.

In the end I got it to work the way I wanted with Soonts' suggestion.

Setting the c++ fileshare option to:

```
txtFile.Open(m_FileName, CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite|CFile::shareDenyWrite, &e)
```

Lets the c# application read the file, but not write to it.

in the c# app reading the file with:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(inputfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

Sets the file access to read only. But setting the file share permissions to readwrite allows the file to be opened while it's being written to by another application. Where I went wrong was having the fileshare permissions be read only as it conflicted with the c++ application before the file was even opened. So it wouldn't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, specify CFile::shareDenyNone or CFile::shareDenyWrite (like you're doing)

In C#, specify FileShare.Write or FileShare.ReadWrite.

Comment: I think I see what was happening. In the c# app where I open the file I set the permissions to FileShare.Read. This means that once the file is open the c# only allows other apps to read the file. But since it's already open in another process it cannot set the file to read only. So I get the error. Setting the file share to readwrite allows the c++ to keep its write permissions and the fileshare settings in the c# app no longer conflict with that, letting the file be opened without the error.